# Can I mix country name and nickname in ExcludeNodes line?

Tags: configuration

When I want to block tor nodes, can I mix country name and nickname and fingerprint or must I only use one of them?

```
ExcludeNodes {de},{dk},{se},{fi},PiratenParteiNRW,358F99684C6AF99282C6909247CACF5B66DA947D
```

additional info after answer:
thank you for answer, just to copy here if somebody needs it:

A list of identity fingerprints, nicknames, country codes and address patterns of nodes to avoid when building a circuit. (Example: `ExcludeNodes SlowServer, ABCD1234CDEF5678ABCD1234CDEF5678ABCD1234, {cc}, 255.254.0.0/8`)

By default, this option is treated as a preference that Tor is allowed to override in order to keep working. For example, if you try to connect to a hidden service, but you have excluded all of the hidden service’s introduction points, Tor will connect to one of them anyway. If you do not want this behavior, set the `StrictNodes` option (documented below).....

Comment: The example from the Tor manual https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en see "ExcludeNodes" suggests that mixing them would be possible.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can mix them.

The example in the [manpage](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) even has that:

```
     ExcludeNodes SlowServer, ABCD1234CDEF5678ABCD1234CDEF5678ABCD1234, {cc}, 255.254.0.0/8
```